# Chrome remote dev tools are disordered, like the screenshot below, even though I remove all the settings

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, android-debug

When I used chrome to debug my Android App WebViews, the remote device tool show like the screenshots. It was disordered, and on the bottom of the window is always blank, like something on it. When I changed the window size, all cell size changed(but changed strange, not predictable), and I still cannot see all cells(Some were hide, some were block by the white, and some were block by other cells which were not what I want). Until now every time I open the remote dev tools, it just like this.

Chrome dev tools to debug common PC webs worked fine, anyone got any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that remote device tools just work for android, so android developers may know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Not a lot of help out there easily find-able. Figured i'd answer here in case some one else comes across this issue and this question:

According to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/qWg3OAGUIOY) the problem is a specific feature used in older webview versions, and the later versions of chrome dev tools not being compatible. Use an older version of chromium as a work around.

[Here's how](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) to identify where to download chromium. I used 62.0.3202 and it fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ben Culmer is correct, but I have detailed description how to deal with it.

Yes, the problem is an old Android and the new Chrome. They are incompatible.

[Here](https://rlz.github.io/programming/2018-04-13/cordova-old-android-debug/) is step by step description how to find and set up old Chromium version to deal with it.